# Allow anonymous user to search custom account field

Tags: users, views

I have a custom account field called *license number*.

How do I allow anonymous users to search for that license number and, after they select it, view that user's profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be covered by the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) in a few steps.

1. Make sure anonymous users have the *Access User Profiles* permission.
2. Create a user view with a page display in the Views UI.
3. Add a exposed filter on your view for your license number field. Set the **Operator**  to *Is equal to* if you want a search by full account number only, or set it to *Contains* if you want a partial/full account number search.
4. Adjust the display how you see fit. The display can contain links to the user profile page.
5. Save the View.

From this point you should now have a page from which to search for user profiles with your custom account number field.

Comment: Hi @Shawn-Conn,  Is there a way to make it so the view does not retrieve all the records until the user types in a license number?

Comment: Yes. For an exposed filter, there's a **Required** checkbox that forces a user to submit data before viewing the results.